# Backup programado con timer, Hilos y Delegados VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, hilos

Tengo un sistema en vb.net el cual tiene la función `HacerBackup()` que se activa con un botón y guarda una copia de seguridad de la base de datos en un dispositivo removible.

Luego el cliente me pidió que ciertos días se haga **automáticamente** cada cierto tiempo y ahi me surgio el problema con estas cuestiones de los hilos.

El siguiente código se encuentra en el evento `Form.Load`, luego de algunos IF (Si el backup programado está activado, que dias lo hará y cada cuanto tiempo)

```
Dim tiempo As Integer = (CInt(TablaConfiguracion.Rows(10)(1)) * 60000) 'Intervalo en minutos
Timer_Backup.Interval = tiempo
Timer_Backup.Enabled = True
```

Luego en el Timer_Backup_Tick llamo a la funcion HacerBackup()

```
Private Sub Timer_Backup_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer_Backup.Tick
    HacerBackup()
End Sub
```

Pero el problema es que cuando realiza el backup (que lleva su tiempo) el programa se detiene hasta que termina. Necesito crear otro **hilo de background** para que haga la compresion de datos y la copia mientras el usuario sigue trabajando.

Como no tengo ni idea sobre Multi-Threading y lo que encontre me resulto inentendible les consulto que métodos o de que forma se puede hacer.

---

**EDITADO:**

Lo resolví utilizando "AddHandler Timer_Backup.Elapsed, AddressOf Timer_Tick" como se ve a continuación:

```
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    'Si esta activado el BACKUP PROGRAMADO llama a la funcion HacerBackup cada X minutos'
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    If TablaConfiguracion.Rows(9)(1) = True Then

        Dim dias As String() = TablaConfiguracion.Rows(11)(1).Split(",")
        Dim hoy As String = Today.DayOfWeek

        'Si esta tildado el dia en preferencias'
        If dias(hoy - 1) = "1" Then
            Dim tiempo As Integer = (CInt(TablaConfiguracion.Rows(10)(1)) * 60000) 'Intervalo en minutos'
            'Aquí creo el timer y le agrego como Handler.Elapsed la dirección de memoria del subproceso Timer_Tick'
            Timer_Backup = New System.Timers.Timer()
            AddHandler Timer_Backup.Elapsed, AddressOf Timer_Tick
            Timer_Backup.Interval = tiempo
            Timer_Backup.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If
```

Pero se me plantea una nueva duda, tengo un **label** en el **Form_Principal** el cual quiero que muestre la fecha y hora del ultimo backup

```
    Shared Sub Timer_Tick(source As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    If HacerBackup() = True Then
        Dim ultimo_backup As String = e.SignalTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm")
        Form_Principal.Label_Principal_UltimoBK.Text = ultimo_backup
    End If
End Sub
```

Pero al ejecutar la instruccion el label no se cambia. Y si la pongo como private me devuelve lo siguiente:

> Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control
>   'Label_Principal_UltimoBK' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que
>   lo creó.

---

**ULTIMO EDIT: (Y Solución definitiva)**

Lo resolví utilizando delegados, como muestro a continuación:

**Funcion delegada:**

```
Delegate Sub DelegadoCambiarLabel(ByVal texto As String)
```

**Funcion que cambia el label:**

```
Private Sub CambiarLabelBackup(ByVal texto As String)
    Me.Label_Principal_UltimoBK.Text = texto
End Sub
```

**Agregandole a la funcion Llamada en cada Tick del timer:**

```
    Private Sub Timer_Tick(source As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    If HacerBackup() = True Then
        Dim ultimo_backup As String = e.SignalTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm")
        'Creamos una instancia del delegado, llamando a la función CambiarLabelBackup'
        Dim Delegado As New DelegadoCambiarLabel(AddressOf CambiarLabelBackup)
        'Invocamos esa instancia y le pasamos como objeto el string en cuestión'
        Me.Invoke(Delegado, New Object() {ultimo_backup})
        TablaConfiguracion(12)(1) = ultimo_backup
        EscribeINI()
    End If
End Sub
```

Y voila! Todo solucionado.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Quizas esto te puede ayudar, ya que cumple con lo que te propones, si lo que buscas es guardar los datos cada cierto tiempo *(Con un control `Timer`)*:

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Partial Public Class Form1 Inherits Form

    Private Sub Form1_Load(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' ... 
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer_Backup_Tick(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer_Backup.Tick
        Dim Thr As New Thread(new ThreadStart(AddressOf BackupManager.HacerBackup))
        Thr.Start()
        ' Esto crea otra entrada para el metodo RealizarBackup y la ejecuta.
    End Sub

End Class
```

Básicamente, solo crea otra entrada para realizar el código en el metodo `HacerBackup()` y luego lo finaliza.

Al código puede que haya que hacerle arreglos que te saldrán en el Error List de Visual Studio *(No soy de VB.NET)*, pero es legible la idea, tambien, te recomiendo usar un timer de `System.Threading`.

Por último, tampoco es muy recomendable hacer backups mientras estas utilizando la base de datos en tu sistema, así que sería mejor ejecutar un backup al hacer operaciones riesgosas y al terminar la ejecución del programa.

Comment: Si yo tampoco estaba muy de acuerdo con hacer un backup programado. Pero fue una negociación entre "Backup mediante click" que yo propuse y "Quiero un backup en cada movimiento" como me pidió el cliente (que por supuesto no entiende lo que significa backup).

Comment: Por lo pronto lo resolvi con {
Timer_Backup = New System.Timers.Timer(); AddHandler Timer_Backup.Elapsed, AddressOf HacerBackup }

Comment: Bueno, preparaselo como el desea y elabora una versión como tu lo planteas y muestrale las diferencias entre ambas cosas, al hacer un backup con cada click vas a sobrecargar el procesador con entradas practicamente innecesarias. Recuerda que instruir a tu cliente es parte de tu trabajo!

Comment: Claro NaCI es justamente lo que le explico, pero es un hueso difícil de roer. No tiene justificación hacer un respaldo de cada movimiento porque tendría un programa lento y un disco sobrecargado de datos innecesarios (que para colmo hay una carpeta con imágenes de cada producto). 
Creo que él plantea que al modificar un registro se escriba en una base de datos paralela por si la principal se daña (que se sobre-escriba).

Comment: Enseñale a usar algun RAID, un backup por cada paso no es la solucion.

Comment: Es curioso ya que se pudiera haber utilizado facilmente un Background Worker

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo que hagas el backup de la base de datos en un programa aparte, es mas si es posible en un servicio que inicie con el sistema, lo del multi threading pues, en c# la ejecución del método timer_eplapsed se hace en un hilo aparte, no sé como sea en Visual Basic.net

acá te dejo un link a un libro (esta en inglés y orientado a c#, pero dado a que los lenguajes son muy similares imagino que podrás adaptarlo a VB.net)  [Developing Windows Services Succinctly](https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/details/ebooks/windowsservices)  en el cual se te muestra como desarrollar servicios para windows (Tambien conocidos como Servicios NT)

para crear un nuevo thread o hilo solo debes utilizar este código:

`Dim thread as New Thread( 
     Sub() 
     HacerBackup() 
      End Sub ) 
thread.Start()`

Comment: Es que es un programa de stock, no tiene mucho sentido que hagan backups cuando el sistema no esta abierto y no se están haciendo movimientos de articulos ni nada. Tendría muchos archivos de backup exactamente iguales. Ademas la base de datos (lo que se comprime y se guarda en el extraible) es un archivo de Access.

Comment: ahh, ok. lo imagine en un entorno con un motor de base de datos como sql server o mysql, donde otras estaciones de trabajo podrian modificar la base de datos.

Comment: `Dim thread as New Thread(
  Sub() 
    HacerBackup()
  End Sub
)
thread.Start()`

Comment: pon esa linea de codigo en el eplapsed del timer

Comment: @Bloodday porfavor edita la respuesta con la información que has añadido al final, así todos pueden verla al instante, y pon información relevante del link para que si un día es link cae, la información pueda estar aquí.